# How to get the 0th index key values in array object

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have one array object in that object **galleryImages** i having like json string , in this galleryImages i want display onely the first image value , how can get the only first image value?

> My array check below

```
$data=Array
(
    [dbResultgallery] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [gallery_id] => 1
                    [className] => 1
                    [sectionName] => 1
                    [title] => Title 1
                    [description] => gfhfg
                    [galleryImages] => ["1.jpeg","2.jpg"]
                    [reg_on] => 2017-04-03 12:21:59
                    [created_by] => soupranjali@gmail.com
                    [school_id] => 2
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [gallery_id] => 2
                    [className] => 1
                    [sectionName] => 1
                    [title] => Title 2
                    [description] => sdfdsfsdfsdfsdf
                    [galleryImages] => ["3.jpeg","4.jpg","5.jpg"]
                    [reg_on] => 2017-04-03 12:23:37
                    [created_by] => soupranjali@gmail.com
                    [school_id] => 2
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

> now i am using json_decode ,see below my code

```
foreach ($dbResultgallery as $gal) : 
    $role = json_decode($gal->galleryImages,true);
 endforeach;
```

> Now i am getting array format like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1.jpeg
        [1] => 2.jpg
    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => 3.jpeg
        [1] => 4.jpg
        [2] => 5.jpg
    )
```

> Expected results

I need only the first images value like **1.jpeg and 3.jpeg**, each array i need only the 0 th key values

Updated code

> var_dump(json_decode($gal->galleryImages,true))

```
array(2) {

 [0]=>
  string(37) "6be1954c4bec91fe26fb7447fc551782.jpeg"
  [1]=>
  string(36) "153651d989591e76444c92cf037d5ac4.jpg"
}

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "f356ceafa408e61cd1c62cfc39752b32.jpeg"
  [1]=>
  string(36) "a4fd29005696d92e0fc4cd3931454609.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(36) "8eaaecdac1ff219192806acba7978a1b.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
$role = json_decode($gal->galleryImages,true)[0];
```

Comment: now getting answer like first string,that means my images values one.jpeg and three,jpg means i am getting answer like o and t

Comment: @subikshanM Ok, what do you get with `var_dump(json_decode($gal->galleryImages,true));`?

Comment: Can you tell me please what is the solution

Comment: @subikshanM If the `var_dump`s are what you posted, then the code currently in my answer will work.

Comment: Ohh sorry sorry , my mistake i have to remove the for loop means your answer working fine very very thanks Mr  Schlaus

Answer (score 0):

```
   foreach ($dbResultgallery as $gal) : 
       if(strpos(json_decode($gal->galleryImages,true) ,"jpeg")!== false){
         echo 'found'; // do your stuff here
       $role = json_decode($gal->galleryImages[0],true);
        }
    endforeach
```

Comment: No based on extension i written the code, for me it won't suitable, i need first index value

Comment: Can you tell me please what is the solution